# Ansible AWS ec2 module with tags and dynamic inventory returns wrong hosts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I have two VPCs under the same account, each of which has several hosts with private IPs.

I have one host with a tag `mobile` equals to `true` and another host with a tag of `Environment` equals to `ci`, both with the same private IP, but they reside in different VPCs.

when I run the following tag search using Ansible:

```
- name: "install security service"
  hosts: "tag_Environment_{{ env }}:&tag_Service_{{ service }}_true"
```

With the arguments `env="ci"` and `service="mobile"`
I get one of the hosts back, even though each of the hosts doesn't have both tags.

Since they have the same IP, it seems like the search is merging the results and thus returns a host which has only one of the tags.

Comment: The scenario doesn't make sense to me. You have two VPCs with the same subnetting, how is the control host supposed to access both hosts if they have the same IP? It can only access the one in the same VPC

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `ec2.py` inventory script uses `vpc_destination_variable` parameter to name hosts.
For VPC it is usually set to `private_ip_address` in [ec2.ini](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/contrib/inventory/ec2.ini#L48), so you can have only one host with same IP in your inventory.

To overcome your situation, you may try play with `instance_filters` to filter hosts before they are saved to inventory.

example from ec2.ini:

```
# Retrieve only instances with (key=value) env=staging tag
# instance_filters = tag:env=staging

# Retrieve only instances with role=webservers OR role=dbservers tag
# instance_filters = tag:role=webservers,tag:role=dbservers

# Retrieve only t1.micro instances OR instances with tag env=staging
# instance_filters = instance-type=t1.micro,tag:env=staging

# You can use wildcards in filter values also. Below will list instances which
# tag Name value matches webservers1*
# (ex. webservers15, webservers1a, webservers123 etc)
# instance_filters = tag:Name=webservers1*
```

Comment: I'm encountering a similar issue. Is there a way to use those filters with parameters from `extra_vars`? can you give an example of what you mean by 'try and play with them'?

Comment: added example from ec2.ini comments to my answer. AFAIK, there is no straightforward way to populate instance_filters from extra vars.